# Appium - Swipe not working on the android device through java code

Tags: java, android, appium

I am new to Appium automation. I am trying to perform swipe on the android device screen and the code below does not works

```
 JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    HashMap<String, Double> swipeObject = new HashMap<String, Double>();
    swipeObject.put("startX", 0.95);
    swipeObject.put("startY", 0.5);
    swipeObject.put("endX", 0.05);
    swipeObject.put("endY", 0.5);
    swipeObject.put("duration", 2.0);
    js.executeScript("mobile: swipe", swipeObject);
```

or

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    HashMap<String, Double> swipeObject = new HashMap<String, Double>();
    swipeObject.put("startX", 600.00);
    swipeObject.put("startY", 685.00);
    swipeObject.put("endX", 198.00);
    swipeObject.put("endY", 550.00);
    swipeObject.put("duration", 2.0);
    js.executeScript("mobile: swipe", swipeObject);;
```

throws an error

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Not yet implemented. Please help us: http://appium.io/get-involved.html (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 16 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.35.0', revision: '8df0c6b', time: '2013-08-12 15:43:19'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 8.1', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.8.0_25'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver
```

If any alternative is available for the swipe, kindly provide the link.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In Ruby language, this line of code works for me to swipe on Android device.Check if this helps.
driver.execute_script 'mobile: swipe', :startX => 700, :startY => 900, :endX => 100, :endY => 900, :duration => 0.8

Comment: I was using latest version of Appium "AppiumForWindows-1.3.4.1", the above code worked fine with "AppiumForWindows-1.2.4.1".

Answer (score 4):

please use (below code will swipe form  Left To Right)

```
    driver.context("NATIVE_APP");
    Dimension size = driver.manage().window().getSize();
    int startX = (int)(size.width * 0.10);
    int endX = (int)(size.width * 0.80);
    int startY = size.height/2;
    driver.swipe(startX, startY, endX, startY, 1000);
```

Comment: of course in example above startY = endY. Typically it's this way: driver.swipe(startX, startY, endX, endY, 1000);

Answer (score 1):

In ruby Lang : 
swipe(start_x: 0.5, start_y: 0.5 , end_x: 0.5, end_y: 0.5, duration: 6) worked for me.

In java you can use "swipe" method within TouchShortcuts interface. please refer http://appium.github.io/java-client/ .

Answer (score 0):

You should use driver.swipe(0.95, 0.5, 0.05, 0.5, 2.0), because other gesture but mobile:scroll/scrollTo is deprecated.

https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/advanced-concepts/migrating-to-1-0.md
Of particular note, the gesture methods have been replaced by the new TouchAction / MultiAction API which allows for a much more powerful and general way of putting gestural automation together. Refer to your Appium client for usage notes on TouchAction / MultiAction.

You can see more information here: https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/4199

Answer (score 0):

driver.swipe(435, 396, 112, 496, 900); It's Best Way to scroll screen in android devices.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, I use the codes below for AndroidDriver

```
androidDriver = new AndroidDriver(capabilities);
WebElement element = androidDriver.findElement(By.xpath(locator));
String originalContext = androidDriver.getContext();
int bottomY = element3.getLocation().getY();
int bottomX = element3.getLocation().getX();
androidDriver.context("NATIVE_APP");
androidDriver.swipe(28, 550, 28, 1, 900);
androidDriver.context(originalContext);
```

I only change the x & y coordinate for modification. Might need to improve to accommodate different screen sizes but this works.